# How to extract values from a complex list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

In Python3

If I have some complex lists such like:

```
[1, [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

or maybe looks like:

```
[1, [2, [3]], 4, [5, 6]]
```

I‘m sure there is no repeat value in this list, but I don't know what the list's exactly  structure is.

how can I extract the values (recursive) from this complex uncertain list?
I want to get a plain list consist of these values:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Is there any elegant way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> flatten([0, [1, 2], [3, 4, [5, 6]], 7])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Try this:

```
import re

def Flatten(TheList):
    a = str(TheList)
    b,crap = re.subn(r'[\[,\]]', ' ', a)
    c = b.split()
    d = [int(x) for x in c]

    return(d)
```

Comment: Input: [1, 2, [3]]    Raise: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: and also doesn't work to [["a", "b", ["d"]], ["c"]]

Comment: changed the solution sorry..

Comment: em, the module compiler has been removed in python3, I have seen [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python). it seems like there isn't any elegant(simply) solution